# Why is global keyword not ignored even if it is unreachable? (Python)

Tags: python, global

**I am really new to programming and *Python*, so please really forgive me for my ignorance.**

I just learned that using `global` can make a variable inside function be a global one.
However, I discovered something not with my expectation:

I tried the following code in *Python 3.8* (forgive me for my ignorance as I don't know what else information I should provide):

```
>>> x = 0
>>> 
>>> def function():
...     if False:
...             global x
...     x = 1
...
>>> function()
>>> print(x)
```

and the result is 1.

However, I expected the code to have the same effect as the following code:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> 
>>> def function():
...     x = 1
...
>>> function()
>>> print(x)
```

which the result should be 0.

In my mind, the statement inside `if False` should **not** be executed, so it sounds strange to me.
Also, personally, I think that in some situation I would expect the variable inside a function, whether local or global, to be dependent on other codes... what I mean is, I would like to change `if False` to something like `if A == 'A'`, while (I hope) I can control whether the `x` is global/local according to my conditional statement.

I tried to change `if` to `while`, but it's the same... there isn't a infinite loop, but the code `global x` is still executed/compiled...

**I admit that it may sounds naive, and perhaps it just won't work in *Python***, but I really wonder why... It seems that the code `global x` is unreachable, but how come it is not ignored?

Can anyone please tell me about the reason? I would like to know more about the mechanism behind compilation(?)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In python the `global` statement (and the `nonlocal` statement) are very different from the normal python code. Essentially no matter where a `global` statement in a function is, it influences always the current codeblock, and is never "executed". You should think more of it as a compiler directive instead of a command.

Note that the statement itself must come before any usage of the variable it modifies, i.e.

```
print(x)
global x
```

is a syntax error. The `global` statement can only modify variable behavior in the whole codeblock, you can't first have a non-global variable that later gets global and you can also not have conditional global variable

(I couldn't really find good documentation for this behavior, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) it says *"The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block."* and *"global is a directive to the parser. It applies only to code parsed at the same time as the global statement."* but that doesn't seem super clear to me.)

There are more compiler directives in python, although they don't always look like one. One is the [`from __future__ import` statements](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) which look like module imports but change python behavior.

Comment: "Essentially no matter where a global statement in a function is, it influences always the whole function from the very beginning"    hm...but it seems that if ```x = 1``` is before ```global x```, there will be a syntaxerror. Also, in the documentation, it says that "Names listed in a global statement must not be used in the same code block textually preceding that global statement."... Would it be better to say that "it influences always the function after it"?

Comment: Hm, you are right. Saying *the function after it* would indicate to me the next function, i.e. if you have nested functions the next function definition, instead of the current function being defined. The docs talk about *the current code block* so maybe that's a better wording?

Comment: Alright...Would you please edit your post to make it clearer?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer and also show the syntax error, do you think it's clear now? Maybe scope as mentioned in ryssons answer is actually the correct word, but the documentation isn't clear on whether python scopes are actually the defining object here or not. I would guess yes, as the property of being global or not is probably saved in the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Global is not in execution path but in a scope. The scope is whole function. Statements like `if` `for` don't make scopes. If you use any assignment you create local variable. The same with `global` or `nonlocal` you bind symbol to variable from outside.

As Stanislas Morbieu typed, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global).

> Programmer’s note: global is a directive to the parser. It applies only to code parsed at the same time as the global statement.

Not at execution time.

```py
x = 1
def fun():
    y = x + 1
    print(f'local x = {x}, y = {y}')
fun()
print(f'global x = {x}')

# Output:
#  local x = 1, y = 2
#  global x = 1
```

In example above, `y` uses *global* `x` (and adds `1`).

```py
x = 1
def fun():
    y = x
    x = y + 1
    print(f'local x = {x}')
fun()
print(f'global x = {x}')

# Output:
#  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Look at last example. It doesn't assign `y` from global `x` because assignment in second line creates local `x` and `y` can not read local `x` before `x` assignment. The same with:

```py
x = 1
def fun():
    if False:
        x += 1
fun()
# Output
#  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

`x` assignment creates local variable.

If you want to change global variable under condition you can use `globals()`.

```py
x = 1
def set_x(do_set, value):
    if do_set:
        globals()['x'] = value
print(f'global x = {x} (init)')
set_x(False, 2)
print(f'global x = {x} (false)')
set_x(True, 3)
print(f'global x = {x} (true)')
# Output
#  global x = 1 (init)
#  global x = 1 (false)
#  global x = 3 (true)
```

### Proxy

I you want to decide with variable you want to use later (in the same scope) you need some kind of proxy IMO.

```py
x = 1
def fun(use_global):
    x = 2  # local
    scope = globals() if use_global else locals()
    scope['x'] += 1
    print(f'local ({use_global}): x = {scope["x"]}')
print(f'global: x = {x} (init)')
fun(False)
print(f'global: x = {x} (false)')
fun(True)
print(f'global: x = {x} (true)')
# Output:
#  global: x = 1 (init)
#  local (False): x = 3
#  global: x = 1 (false)
#  local (True): x = 2
#  global: x = 2 (true)
```

Maybe you can think about refactoring of your code if you need it.

If you can change local variable name (if not use `globals()` as above), you can proxy:

- use dict (like in example above)
- use list (`x=[1]`) and usage `x[0]`
- use object (with builtin dict), example:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

x = X(1)
def fun(use_global):
    global x
    my_x = x if use_global else X(2)
    my_x.x += 1
    print(f'local ({use_global}): x = {my_x.x}')

print(f'global: x = {x.x} (init)')
fun(False)
print(f'global: x = {x.x} (false)')
fun(True)
print(f'global: x = {x.x} (true)')

# Output:
#  global: x = 1 (init)
#  local (False): x = 3
#  global: x = 1 (false)
#  local (True): x = 2
#  global: x = 2 (true)
```

**Note.** Variables in Python are only references. It is way you can not change `x = 1` without `global` (or `globals()`). You change reference to local value `1`.
But you can change `z[0]` or `z['x']` or `z.x`. Because `z` referents to list or dict or object and you modify it content.

**See:** https://realpython.com/python-variables/#object-references
You can check real object by `id()` function, ex. `print(id(x), id(my_x))`.

Comment: Excuse me, but did you miss a call of function in the first example of code?

Comment: @TonyMa, sure. I've added  `fun()` call. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but is it necessary to use ```global()['x'] = value```? I mean, the conditional statement ```if do_set``` will decide whether there is an assignment, so isn't it the same to have ```global x``` and then ```x = value```? Actually, I am wondering how to make the following situation possible: I would use x later, but it may be local x or global x, depending on a condition.

Comment: `global()['x'] = value` was used to point how to access to global variable without `global`. It could be useful if you want to use local `x` and sometimes (condition) set global. 
If you decide local ob global and than use `x` I think it's not possible without some kind of proxy. I'll add example in my answer soon.

Comment: I wonder why in the last code example, when ```use_global``` is ```True```, ```my_x``` will kind of return value to ```x```. ```my_x = x```, but isn't ```my_x``` a local object? Or there is no such *local object*?

Comment: Yes and no :) `my_x` is local reference to... global `x` (if `use_global`). Try to follow µ-example:
x[0] = 1
def fun():
    x[0] += 1

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), `global` is a directive to the parser so it is taken into account before the execution, therefore it does not matter if the code is reachable or not. The variable is global for the entire scope, which is the function in your case.